# Play WMA Files in CF.NET 2.0

Tags: .net, compact-framework, audio

I'm using this code from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229685(VS.80).aspx) to play audio notifications for my application.  It's working fine when the user chooses a wav file, but it doesn't play when they choose a wma file.

Is there any way I can support wma files?  A lot of the built-in alarm and ringtones seem to be wma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And to answer my own question again, I found that using the following works in WM6:
[DllImport("aygshell.dll")]
internal static extern uint SndPlaySync(string file, uint flags);

This doesn't work in WM5 though, so I fall back to the old method to play wav files there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Windows Media Player Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930695.aspx).

According to the documentation, you should be able to play WMA files.